# What is the equivalent of get_collection for the frozen/inference model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

So in my testing I purely used a checkpoint to test the model, using a checkpoint, I can get the tensors and variables via get_collection easily once I restore my model using saver.restore(ckpt)

My problem is this is no longer the same for a .pb model. get_collections("logits") no longer works.

My question is how do I make it work for the .pb/frozen/inference model?

Here is my code used to test the checkpoints, I surrounded the non-working line with asterisks:

```
input = graph.get_tensor_by_name("model_input:0")
seq_len = graph.get_tensor_by_name("seq_lengths:0")
rnn_keep_prob = graph.get_tensor_by_name("keep_prob:0")
height_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_height:0")
width_reduction_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("width_reduction:0")
**logits = tf.get_collection("logits")[0]**

**decoded, _ = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits, seq_len)**
```

This is the model definition that contains the "logits" that I need to access:

```
# Recurrent block
rnn_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="keep_prob")
rnn_hidden_units = params['rnn_units']
rnn_hidden_layers = params['rnn_layers']

rnn_outputs, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
    tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
        [tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_hidden_units), input_keep_prob=rnn_keep_prob)
         for _ in range(rnn_hidden_layers)]),
    tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
        [tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_hidden_units), input_keep_prob=rnn_keep_prob)
         for _ in range(rnn_hidden_layers)]),
    features,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    time_major=True,
)

rnn_outputs = tf.concat(rnn_outputs, 2)

logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    rnn_outputs,
    params['vocabulary_size'] + 1,  # BLANK
    activation_fn=None,
)

tf.add_to_collection("logits",logits) # for restoring purposes

# CTC Loss computation
seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='seq_lengths')
targets = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name='target')
ctc_loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels=targets, inputs=logits, sequence_length=seq_len, time_major=True)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(ctc_loss)

# CTC decoding
decoded, log_prob = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits, seq_len)
# decoded, log_prob = 
tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(logits,seq_len,beam_width=50,top_paths=1,merge_repeated=True)
```

Comment: (I've removed my response regarding TensorFlow Lite models as your question only pertains to TensorFlow models)